# AES encryption in POSTRGESQL

Tags: java, postgresql, encryption, bytea, pgcrypto

I used a function in `pgcrypto` - `encrypt('id','TheBestSecretKey','aes')` to encrypt a field in `postgresql(Pg admin tool)`.The field got encrypted and the output was in bytea format like:`\234u\321\036\027\317O\371\020bb\342\334x)\236`. The same data when encrypted using aes (using javax.crypto library) in java gave me string output as : `œuÑÏOùbbâÜx)ž` .
I have a requirement where I need to compare both these values in my java program. How can I compare these two fields.

Comment: That is a weird requirement. Ciphertext should always be "salted" with a random IV, so that if you encrypt the same text twice it *does not* result in the same ciphertext. Otherwise you can do dictionary attacks. The only way to get anything useful from "proper" ciphertext is to decrypt it.

Comment: `Arrays.toString(data.toByteArray())`

Comment: Having said that, are you sure these two outputs are not the same? They have the same length, and all the readable characters `u`, `b` and `)` are in the same positions.

Comment: @Thilo These are the encrypted value of the same data .One encrypted in postgresql the other in  a java program.Both are encrypted using aes with the same key.

Comment: @bhavanak: Yes. And they look the same to me. Look at the byte values in Java, too (don't turn it into a String).